# how to get path of custom xml file in magento2

Tags: magento2

I created xml file in my module etc folder.i want to read this xml file and store into variable as a string.

```
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $read

$XMLGetRequest=$this->read->readFile('here i need xml file path');
```

Comment: Do you know the name of xml file?

Comment: yes.etc/paymentschema.xml

Comment: so do you want to find a path to this one file? Or you want to find all files with this name?
Could you clarify your question?

Comment: this one file only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use **\Magento\Framework\Xml\Parser** and **\Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader**

Something like this:

```
 class YourClass 
 {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader
         */
        protected $moduleDirReader;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Xml\Parser
         */
        private $parser;

            ...

        public function getValue() 
        {
            $filePath = $this->moduleDirReader->getModuleDir('etc', 'Your_Module') 
               . '/paymentschema.xml'
            $parsedArray = $this->parser->load($filePath)->xmlToArray();
            return $parsedArray['xmlNodeName'];
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

there is actually a way to create a new configuration object in magento2 that can parse your configuration and validate it through an xsd all automatically.

I know they mentioned it in a fundamentals course but I can't find any reference now.

**===UPDATE===**

I think this is it:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/config/config-create.html

Under Create Configuration Types

Comment: Actually i dont need to validate and get particular node.simply i need to store into a variable as a string.

Comment: ok i get that, then there is the simple and the right way ;)